# Is Nested Selection equivalent to AC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

**Nested Selection:** For every infinite set $G$ of pairwise disjoint infinite sets such that any two distinct elements $x,y$ of $G$ either "$y$ is a set of proper supersets of elements of $x$ and each element of $x$ has a proper superset of it in $y$" or "$x$ is a set of proper supersets of elements of $y$ and each element of $y$ has a proper superset of it in $x$"; there exists a set $cG$ that is a choice set on $G$ (i.e. $cG$ is a subset of $\bigcup G$ that has exactly one element from each element of $G$, among its elements) and such that for any two elements $a,b$ of $cG$ we have $a$ subset of $b$ or $b$ subset of $a$.

> Is Nested selection equivalent to $AC$?

The formal capture is a little bit messy. It is:

$\forall G: \operatorname {infinite} (G) \land \forall h \in G (\operatorname {infinite}(h)) \land \\ \forall k,l \in G (k \neq l \to k \cap l = \emptyset)  \land \\ \forall x,y \in G (\forall z \in y [x] \exists u \in x [y] (z \supsetneq u) \land \\ \forall v \in x[y] \exists w \in y[x] (w \supsetneq v) ) \\ \implies \\ \exists cG: cG \subseteq \bigcup G \land \\\forall g \in G \exists! m (m \in g \land m \in cG) \land \\\forall a,b \in cG: a \subseteq b \lor b \subseteq a$

> If the above nested selection is too particular theme to pace with Choice.Then is the following general form equivalent to choice?

Define $\begin{align} Y \text { is } \Phi\text{-image of } X \iff &\forall a \in X \exists b \in Y: \Phi(a,b) \land \\ &\forall b \in Y \exists a \in X: \Phi(a,b)\end{align}$

**General Nested Selection:** If $\Phi$ is a transitive asymmetric binary relation, then if $G$ is an infinite set of pairwise disjoint infinite sets such that every two distinct sets $X,Y \in G$ either $ Y \text { is } \Phi\text{-image of } X $ or $ X \text { is } \Phi\text{-image of } Y$; then there exists a choice set $C$  on $G$ such that for any two distinct elements $a,b \in C$ either $ \Phi(a,b)$ or $\Phi(b,a)$.

By $C$ being a choice set on $G$ it means that $C \subseteq \bigcup G$ and $C$ shares exactly one element with each element of $G$.

Comment: Nested selection is false.  If $G$ is a set of $\subseteq$-comparable sets, then there is no choice set $cG$ because if $x,y \in cG$ and $x \in A \in G$, $y \in B \in G$, then either $x,y \in A$ or $x,y \in B$ since either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, $G$ must have all its elements being pairwise disjoint, I missed putting that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your definition.  Please clarify what you mean by "$y$ is a proper supersets of elements of $x$".  Do you mean that for some $z \in x$, $y \supseteq x$?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, you missed reading "set", "$y$ is a "set" of proper supersets of elements of $x$". It means every element of $y$ is a proper superset of an element of $x$ and every element of $x$ has some proper superset of it in $y$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: If that’s what you mean, then the phrasing is very misleading!  I would have understood “$y$ is a set of proper supersets of elements of $x$” to mean “for each $z \in y$, there’s some $u \in x$ such that $z \supsetneq u$”, or possibly with a different order of quantification; but generally “$y$ is a set of [somethings]” is always only claiming something about the elements of $y$ — it really can’t be taken to include something like the second half of what you say you mean by it, “every element of $x$ has some proper superset of it in $y$”.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, would writing "all" makes matters clearer, that is $y$ is a set of proper supersets of "all" elements of $x$.

Comment: No — “$y$ is a set of proper supersets of all elements of $x$” is again somewhat ambiguous, but my first guess would be that it means “every element of $y$ is a proper subset of all elements of $x$”.  When in doubt, just be clear and explicit about your quantification — say e.g. “each element of $y$ is a proper subset of some element of $x$, and each element of $x$ has some proper subset in $y$”, or similar.  There’s no need to write so ambiguously!

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, OK, then I'll see how to phrase it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some natural example fulfilling the hypothesis?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, which one you are asking about, the general one or the proper superset one? OK, a natural example would be a set of Frege-Russell-Scott ordinals\cardinals.

Comment: Looks to me like ZF + the principle is inconsistent. Can't you use it to produce an injection $f:\omega_1\to\omega$? Consider the natural forcing whose generic object is such a function (conditions are proper segments of the function). Turn this into a nested collection of the kind in the definition (consider the set $A_f$ of all forcing conditions extending a given condition $f$, and for a given $\alpha<\omega_1$, the set of all $A_f$'s where $f$ has domain $\alpha$), ...

Comment: ... and such that a choice function of the kind specified corresponds to an injection $f:\omega_1\to\omega$.

Comment: @FarmerS, well I don't know, if you think it works then that would be the answer!

Comment: @FarmerS, I though it's consistent relative to Global choice.

Comment: Why did you ask this question?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, I thought about this while trying to prove a result about ordinals in NF, in particular I wanted to know its stance from choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample to Nested Selection, construct sets $A_\alpha\subseteq\omega$ ($\alpha\lt\omega_1$) so that, for $\alpha\lt\beta\lt\omega_1$, we have $|A_\alpha\setminus A_\beta|\lt\aleph_0=|A_\beta\setminus A_\alpha|$. Let $\mathcal S_\alpha=\{X\subseteq\omega:|X\triangle A_\alpha|\lt\aleph_0\}$ and let $G=\{\mathcal S_\alpha:\alpha\lt\omega_1\}$. A choice set for $G$ which was totally ordered by inclusion would be a chain of length $\omega_1$ in $\mathcal P(\omega)$, which doesn't exist.

**P.S.** To construct the sets $A_\alpha$, first partition $\omega$ into infinitely many disjoint infinite sets $N_i$ ($i\lt\omega$), and then define $A_\alpha$ recursively for $\alpha\lt\omega_1$ so that $|A_\alpha\cap N_i|\lt\aleph_0$ for each $i\lt\omega$ and $|A_\beta\setminus A_\alpha|\lt\aleph_0=|A_\alpha\setminus A_\beta|$ for each $\beta\lt\alpha$.

Comment: are the $\mathcal S_\alpha$ sets pairwise disjoint?

Comment: Yes, since $A_\alpha\triangle A_\beta$ is infinite when $\alpha\ne\beta$.